# A* search algorithm with an example

Tags: algorithm, graph, greedy

I am investigating the A* search algorithm, and came across this example:

[image]

The description of the algorithm is as follows:

> Visiting node 0 with currently lowest priority of 8.0
>
> Updating distance of node 1 to 3 and priority to 9.32455532033676
>
> Updating distance of node 2 to 4 and priority to 10.32455532033676
>
> Visiting node 1 with currently lowest priority of 9.32455532033676
>
> Updating distance of node 3 to 9 and priority to 11.82842712474619
>
> Updating distance of node 4 to 13 and priority to 15.82842712474619
>
> Visiting node 2 with currently lowest priority of 10.32455532033676
>
> Visiting node 3 with currently lowest priority of 11.82842712474619
>
> Updating distance of node 5 to 12 and priority to 12.0
>
> Goal node found!

I am wondering how the priority numbers have been derived. Here's the website, where this information was taken from:

https://www.algorithms-and-technologies.com/a_star/r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Euclidean distance is used as heuristic. The actual costs are the labels.

For example at node 1, the G cost is 3 (the edge from node 0) and the H cost is `sqrt(2² + 6²)`, making the F cost 9.32455532033676.

Comment: I understand the G cost, but how were 2 and 6 derived. Thanks.

Comment: @Danny node 1 has a vertical distance of 2 from the goal, and a horizontal distance of 6

Comment: What would be the vertical and horizontal distances of node 2. One of them should be 2.4, but I am not sure about the other.

Comment: @Danny 2,4 are the coordinates of the node, the distance to the goal (at 8,2) is also 2 vertical and 6 horizontal